# How to get a modal when a checkbox is selected?

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

Here are my codes

**ex1.php**

```
<body>

<form>

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="LH" name="name">LH</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="LJ" name="name">LJ</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="LL" name="name">LL</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="FA" name="name">FA</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="FB" name="name">FB</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="FU" name="name">FU</label>
</form>

<!--modal-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?php

        $test = $_POST['test'];

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";


// Create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);


// Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        echo "Connected successfully";

        mysqli_connect_db("db",$conn);

        $sql = "SELECT Subcat FROM subcat where CatId=".$test." ";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='category[]' value='".$row['Subcat']."'>"
        .$row['Subcat'];
        echo "<br>";   
}
        ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
```

**ex1.js**

```
$document.ready(function(){
    $(":checkbox").click(function(){
        var value_ck = $(this).val();
        $.ajax(
            url:"ex1.php",
            type:"post",
            data:{test:value_ck},
            success:function(){
                $("#myModal").modal();




                });
    });
});
```

What I want to do here is as follows

I have a checkbox list in the form. When I click a checkbox ,a modal should appear with corresponding data coming from the database.I am a very beginner to `Jquery`. My codes are not working.I Found solutions everywhere to fix that. but I was unable .

Could anyone please to help me?

Comment: Use `$("INPUT[type=checkbox]")` instead of `$(":checkbox")`. Also need to put modal to separate php file.

Comment: u can do it in two ways like :)
1 )give the model open class name to checkbox (means for model pop up when u click on a button or any link a model pop up will open so take that values and put in check box) 2) in ajax success trigger the click function

Comment: @NikolayKrasnov , why I should put the modal in separate php file? Could u explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not familiar with JSON/api things, do like that:

**ex1.php**

```
<body>

<form>

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="LH" name="name">LH</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="LJ" name="name">LJ</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="LL" name="name">LL</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="FA" name="name">FA</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="FB" name="name">FB</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="FU" name="name">FU</label>
</form>

<!--modal-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

**modal.php**

```
<?php

            $test = $_POST['test'];

            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";


    // Create connection
            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);


    // Check connection
            if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }
            echo "Connected successfully";

            mysqli_connect_db("db",$conn);

            $sql = "SELECT Subcat FROM subcat where CatId=".$test." ";
            $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='category[]' value='".$row['Subcat']."'>"
            .$row['Subcat'];
            echo "<br>";   
    }
?>
```

**ex1.js**

```
$document.ready(function(){
    $("INPUT[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
        var value_ck = $(this).val();
        $.ajax(
            url:"modal.php",
            type:"post",
            data:{test:value_ck},
            success:function(modalBody){
                $("#myModal .modal-body").html(modalBody);
                $("#myModal").modal();
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

To open a model with id `myModal` and

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

to hide the modal

after loading the data from a post request populate the model with values in `success:function()` and use `$('#myModal').modal('show')` to show the model to the user